# VSCode autocompletes Typescript angle bracket generics, as if they were xml tags

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I have a super annoying issue.

When I'm writing some typescript, and I define a generic like `export interface MyInterface<T>|`, then as soon as I have typed the closing `>` then VSCode autocompletes it to `export interface MyInterface<T>|</T>`.

What is causing this, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: I had a couple of 'auto tag complete' extensions, which I disabled to solve it.

Comment: Note: There *is* an option to `[ ] Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style` - Do tell *which* extensions you had trouble with.

Comment: "Auto Close Tag" was causing it for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) VSCode extension, it provides the ability to configure both enabling and disabling auto-completion for file types in your `settings.json` file.

> To get to your settings.json file:
>
> 1. Open the command panel with <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
> 2. Search for "Settings (JSON)"

You could add either a whitelist (the ones you would like to have completion for) by adding the `auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage` key in your `settings.json` file like this:

```
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
  "xml",
  "markdown",
  "HTML (EEx)",
  "HTML (Eex)"
]
```

Or, you could add a blacklist (the ones you would like to not have completion for) by adding the `auto-close-tag.disableOnLanguage` key in your `settings.json` file like this:

```
"auto-close-tag.disableOnLanguage": [
  "php",
  "javascript",
  "typescript",
  "plaintext",
]
```

Here is a full list of the default currently allowed languages/file types in case you would like to add one of these back in. The full list is also visible in the documentation on the [VSCode extension's homepage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag).

```
"auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
  "xml",
  "php",
  "blade",
  "ejs",
  "jinja",
  "javascript",
  "javascriptreact",
  "typescript",
  "typescriptreact",
  "plaintext",
  "markdown",
  "vue",
  "liquid",
  "erb",
  "lang-cfml",
  "cfml",
  "HTML (EEx)",
  "HTML (Eex)",
  "plist"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension was causing this issue. After uninstalling this extension, the problem went away.

Comment: saved my day, was having the same problem